# Grails REST controller shows delete action for get

Tags: rest, grails, url-mapping

I have a RESTful controller (Grails 2.3.11):

```
class LookupController extends RestfulController {
    static responseFormats = ['json', 'xml', 'html']
    LookupController() {
        super(Lookup)
    }
    @Override
    protected List<Lookup> listAllResources(Map params) {
        log.debug(params)
        return super.listAllResources(params)
    }
```

With this in UrlMappings:
    "/api/lookups"(resources:"lookup")

When I do a GET of

```
http://localhost:8080/api/lookups
```

I see this in the log file:

```
DEBUG controller.LookupController  - [action:delete, controller:lookup, max:10]
```

The apparent action is delete!  Why is this?  What's wrong?

Answer (score 2):

This is a bug in grails prior to 2.4.4 (https://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-11748).
Should be fixed when updating to Grails 2.4.4